# Objective-C. Using blocks to reduce amount of code?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, block, codeblocks

For example, I need to implement an object moving. It is left, right, up and down methods.

**Edited**

The following code is incorrect but I hope it will explain the thing I need better:

```
@interface A : NSObject
...
@end

@implementation A
-(void)up
{
  [self moveTo:^{/*block1*/}];
}

-(void)down
{
    [self moveTo:^{/*block2*/}];
}

-(void)left
{
  [self moveTo:^{/*block3*/}];
}

-(void)right
{
  [self moveTo:^{/*block4*/}];
}

-(void)moveTo:(CodeBlock *)b {
  //actions before
 ...
  b
  //actions after
 ...
}
@end
```

Comment: Tark almost solved my problem. The problem remained is when these methods I need to differ are in one class. For example draw1, draw2, draw3...

Comment: Using lambdas is a very nice approach. But after editing your question it changed from confusing to non-existing ;) What do you want to know?

Comment: I have found the solution by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution**

For my example:

```
-(void)left
{
    [self moveTo:^(CGPoint p) {
        p.x--;
        return p;
    }];
}

-(void)moveTo:(CGPoint(^)(CGPoint))block
{
    CGPoint p = sprite.position;
    p = block(p);
    sprite.position = p;
}
```

Right, up and down methods are similar to left method. So don't told me that it is incorrect question or that the solution is impossible

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear, but from the Java code snippet it sounds like you want to call a method on multiple classes. This is very simple in Obj-C, as it is a dynamic language. You can simply cast the object as type `id` and call any method on it, as long as that object has that method implemented.

To do this more formally, you would define a protocol:

```
@protocol Drawable <NSObject>
- (void)draw;
@end
```

Then any class that needs to implement this protocol can declare it in the header:

```
@interface A : NSObject <Drawable>
```

Then simply implement the method in class A. The method signature in class C would become:

```
- (void)show:(id<Drawable>)r
{
    [r draw];
}
```

Another simple solution would be to use a class hierarchy, with the superclass implementing the `-(void)draw` method, and every subclass that needed a different implementation could override it.

Comment: +1, but not an answer. What to do if I have any class A with methods draw1, draw2, draw3 and I must recognize them all? Is it possible with if or case blocks only?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Why can't you add all of the methods to the protocol? Can you edit the question to be a bit clearer?

Comment: I have edited again. I hope it will be more clear now.
I can't add these methods into one protocol because I should differ these methods between themselves (not the same methods from various classes). But thank you anyway for a temporary solution

Comment: I'm sorry, it is still unclear what you are not able to achieve. What is wrong with the solution you have?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i get what you mean but you in objective C you use setters and getters to modify your variables. So in your implementation of the instance object you can write code which affects your ivars directly.

I suppose you have position defined as a property, and that's why you say you cannot assign it.

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint position;
```

However in the implementation if you set your:

```
@synthesize position = _position;
```

then you can modify it directly like this

```
_position.x++;
```

which means you can write a method that is something like

```
-(void) moveLeftBy:(int) x
{
    _position.x += x;
}
```

If this is not what you mean, please be more explicit in your question.

Comment: position is predefined in cocos2d library. I used this as example only. There could be much more difficult code. such as preparing the network connection, serializing an object and sending via this network and deserializing an answer object

Answer (score 0):

You can write one combined method that handles the difference by checking an argument:

```
(void)methodNameCombined:(NSInteger)direction
{
    ...
    switch(direction) {
        case 1:
            x++;
            break;
        case 2:
            y++;
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```

and call this one from your specific methods

```
(void)methodNameUp
{
    [self methodNameCombined:1]
}

(void)methodNameRight
{
    [self methodNameCombined:2]
}
...
```

Comment: At least if you advice me this example you should define all the possible directions to use them without numbers which you can mix up. The second, you advice to check the function-sender manually and it is bad.

Comment: It's an answer to your original question: a known amount of methods (up, down, left, right) differ in one line, how to minimize redundant code? Keep simple tasks simple and readable.

Comment: Look at my solution now and compare with your one

Comment: I like your solution as I like mine. Maybe there are even more working patterns, try to find them :)